# How to encrypt a bank account number using ANSI X9.8

Tags: algorithm, encryption, .net-core

I have a requirement to encrypt a bank account number using the ANSI X9.8 encryption method using .net core. I couldn't find any built-in libraries for that. how can I do this?

Comment: It's a `XOR` between two values, why would you want a library to do that? You can see it here if you look for "ISO format 0": https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19321-01/E39851/5_FS.html

Answer (score -2):

The ANSI docs are behind a paywall, but found an excerpt from [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap15.pdf) that mentions X9.8 is DES.  Have you looked at [OpenSSL with a .Net shim/wrapper](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net) ?